# Does autoload load all functions in the file or just the one specified?

Tags: hooks, libraries

I have developed some private extensions to some major modes, and I would like to load those extensions only when the given major mode is actually used by the user. The extensions consists of a set of functions confined to a single file. For example, for `emacs-lisp-mode`, I have developed a file `"~/emacs/my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook.el`, here is a minimal example for illustration purposes:

```el
(defun my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook ()
  (my-hook-func))

(defun my-hook-func ()
  (message-box "This is my hook function"))
```

And then, in my Emacs init file `~/.emacs` I have:

```el
(autoload 'my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook "~/emacs/my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook.el" "My Emacs Lisp mode hook" nil nil)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook)
```

Note that I do not have an `autoload` call for the function `my-hook-func`.
The question is: If it is sufficient to call `autoload` only for the function `my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook`, or if I have to call `autoload` for each function in the file `"~/emacs/my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook.el`? The idea is that, the other functions in the file will never be used unless a buffer switches to major mode `emacs-lisp-mode` and the hook function `my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook` has run.

Currently, this strategy seems to work (I get the message box created in `my-hook-func` even if I have no explicit `autoload` statement for that function). But I could not find a clear statement of this behavior in the manual. So is this a viable strategy? (It would certainly allow me to simplify my code, that is: not having to add autoload cookies for each function, and not call `update-file-autoloads` and so on..)

Comment: And BTW, you don't need to (and shouldn't) autoload hooks. Just calling add-hook will work even if the hook is not defined yet.

Comment: @Malabarba I guess you are talking about the case where the hook function is loaded later by the Emacs init file.. I am not considering that case, I am considering the case where the hook is  defined in a another file that is not loaded yet (and not will be loaded later, unless I had used `autoload` to inform Emacs in which file to find the hook)..

Comment: actually I was talking about the hook itself. But I see now I misread your question. You're autoloading the function, not the hook. Just ignore me. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once a single autoloaded call is triggered, the whole file will be required.

The common strategy is to put `;;;###autoload` on the user interface entry points: the most
used interactive functions. For instance, for a minor mode, usually only the minor mode definition
needs to be autoloaded.

### Finding the following info

> The "autoload" facility lets you register the existence of a function
>   or macro, but put off loading the file that defines it.  The first call
>   to the function automatically loads the proper library, in order to
>   install the real definition and other associated code, then runs the
>   real definition as if it had been loaded all along.  Autoloading can
>   also be triggered by looking up the documentation of the function or
>   macro

- <kbd>F1 i</kbd> to launch `info`
- <kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)` to go to Elisp node
- <kbd>i</kbd> `autoload` to search the index for the word autoload
- that's it, the topic is the first one (out of thirteen) in the index

Comment: Thanks @abo-abo! Then I think my strategy will work also :) Could you find a reference to the place in the manual where this behavior is stated?

Answer (score 4):

Consider ***asking Emacs*** first.

`C-h r` `i autoload` takes you to node `Lisp Libraries` in the Emacs manual, where you see, among other things:

> Some commands are "autoloaded"; when you run them, Emacs
>   automatically ***loads the associated library*** first.  For instance, the
>   `M-x compile` command (*note Compilation::) is autoloaded; if you call
>   it, Emacs automatically loads the `compile` library first.  In
>   contrast, the command `M-x recompile` is not autoloaded, so it is
>   unavailable until you load the `compile` library.

Not that it says clearly that it loads the **library** where the command is defined, not just the command definition.

When you use `i autoload` a message tells you:

> Found `autoload` in Concept Index.  (2 total; use `,` for next)

That is, this is not the only node indexed for **"autoload"**; there is one more. And if you hit `,` then Emacs takes you to node `Init Examples`, where you see this:

> - Tell Emacs to find the definition for the function `myfunction` by
>      loading a Lisp library named `mypackage` (i.e., a file
>      `mypackage.elc` or `mypackage.el`):
>
>   ```
>    (autoload 'myfunction "mypackage" "Do what I say." t)
>   ```

Again, note that it tells you that autoloading loads a library.

You will of course find much more detail about autoloading in the Elisp manual, but even this cursory glance at the Emacs manual provides the answer to your question.

*Ask Emacs.*

Comment: Thanks @Drew for the help on how to search the included Emacs manual! Good to know, but it seems like it is easier to search the [online manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html) with Google. BTW, when I press `C-h r` I get the Emacs manual, is there keyboard shortcut to open the Emacs Lisp manual also? (I tried `C-h C-h` but could not find any...)

Comment: There is no predefined key sequence for the Elisp manual, but you can of course define your own. And `C-h i` opens Info to the directory of all manuals, so `C-h i m` followed by a char or two is, in effect, a shortcut for any given manual. E.g., `C-h i m g RET` opens the Gnus manual.

Comment: Is it really easier to use Google?  The indices in the Emacs manual are pretty good and you will only find information useful for the installed version.